# export ssrs report data into multiple excel files

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am calling reports through Data Driven Subscriptions. We are having very huge data (in millions). So the reports will be generating very large excel files.

We have provided download option to user for downloading created report excel files. But if file sizes are very huge, User is not able to dowload the files.

Does anyone have an idea how to split report data to multiple excel files. Does SSRS can handle it? After some size limit split data to next file. Like generate multiple files for same report call.

Answer (score 1):

You can split the records into multiple shits by going to page break option in report properties.or you can go to tool tip and write custom expressipn there to how much data you want to see in one shit.

or you can use the help of SSIS to split the report into miltiple excel work book.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no feature in SSRS that handles this.

You will have to roll your own solution: generate the report asynchronosly (or scheduled) server side, then create an application to distribute the files in seperate parts.